# Re configure TFS 2012 reporting services

Tags: team-foundation-server, sql-server-2012

I have a TFS 2012 installation that is working perfectly. I've installed TFS using advanced configuration and choose to not configure at that moment the Reporting and Sharepoint  features.

Now, I want to configure the Reporting but when I try to do this, the configuration tool throws an error (with an error code that I googled with NO results).

http://tinyurl.com/bpebbn8

```
Error code: TF400465
A required component is not installed on the application tier. You must install either 
SQL Server Analysis Services...
```

The SQL Server has Analysis Services installed and the SQL Client Tools too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with your SQL Server topology.

It sounds like maybe you have Database Engine, Analysis services and client tools all on the SQL Server, but none of those features on the TFS server? If that's true, then you need to run the SQL Server setup on the TFS server (DEVSERVER) and install SQL Client tools on the *TFS* application tier, as it says in the (somewhat) cryptic error message.

Here is the page on MSDN that talks about SQL Server topology for TFS (see recommendation for SQL Server topology):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578652.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: Great man, I have no idea that I have to install those components in the TFS server. I will try your recommendations and notify the results. Thank you very much!

Comment: You only need to add client tools to tfs to get it to work. No need to move analysis server onto tfs. It should run just fine by adding client tools. Good luck.